# Large postscript print job fails

Tags: postscript

I'm working on a program that prints many pages using postscript.  If I print a few pages everything prints correctly.  However, if I print a large document, say 100 pages, it stops around page 21.  It waits for a minute then spits out an error on the next page.  I'm sending the information directly to the printer one character at a time, if that makes any difference.  If I remove pages from the job prior to the error it prints those pages fine, but gets another error 20 or so pages down the road.  I have a temporary fix where it connects to the printer, prints 10 pages, then closes the connection and starts over with a new connection every 10 pages.  This prints everything fine.  The amount of data transmitted is just over a meg and my printer has 32 meg of memory, so there should be plenty of buffer space.  Sometimes the offending command is only part of a command and not complete, like 'how' instead of 'show'.

The file is here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2430447/SPL0333842

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting the PostScript language file which causes the problem.  It's very hard to answer questions like yours without seeing the code.

The symptoms you describe are typical of a page description which runs out of memory.  In your file, the glaring problem is this line, which occurs on every page:
    -2 vmreclaim

According to the [**PostScript Language Reference**, third edition](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf), page 716,

> *int* `vmreclaim –`
>   controls the garbage collection machinery as specified by *int*:
>   -2 Disables automatic collection in both local and global VM...

"Garbage collection" here refers to the PostScript interpreter's way of reusing memory which was used earlier by your file but is no longer needed. In other words, your file is intentionally disabling the interpreter's mechanism for reclaiming memory. So, the very first thing to try is removing all instances of `-2 vmreclaim`.

There are other ways in which your file is structured with poor style.  It is not divided into prolog and script as recommended by the [**Document Structuring Conventions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Structuring_Conventions). You seem to be having the PostScript interpreter perform text layout, especially in procedure `/Truncate`.  You use the special comment `!PS-Adobe` throughout the file, instead of at the beginning of the file.

Still, I expect those issues didn't stop the file from printing; or even, in this era of fast processors, slow it down much.  Stop forbidding memory reuse, and you are likely to stop running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

1. Who is the originator of the PostScript you are sending?
2. Is the target printer a PostScript consuming one, or is there some kind of conversion happening between your printing host and the printer device?
3. How big (in Bytes) is the 100 page PostScript file that fails on page 21?
4. Can you tell us more details about the 'offending command' errors you seem to see?!
5. Is it possible that you provide a link to a sample PostScript file?
6. How is the printer connected to your printing host? (Is it, for example, sitting behind a small "print server" appliance box which provides network connectivity, while the printer hangs off a USB connection from appliance to printer?)
7. Did you check all the cables?
8. Does the following code print 100 pages?

   ```
   %!PS
   /H1 {/Helvetica findfont 48 scalefont setfont .2 .2 1 setrgbcolor} def
   /pageframe  {1 0 0 setrgbcolor 2 setlinewidth 10 10 575 822 rectstroke} def
   /gopageno {H1 300 700 moveto } def
   1 1 100 {pageframe gopageno
   4 string cvs
   dup stringwidth pop
   -1 mul 0 rmoveto
   show
   showpage} for
   ```

Comment: I am creating the PostScript myself.  If I alter my program to terminate the connection with the printer then reconnect every 10 pages everything works fine.  Also, if I choose to print only 40 pages everything prints fine.  I have a USB cable directly from my computer to the printer.  The files are about 1.1mb.  I'll try your code.  If I do get an offending command, it looks like the command what broken.  Like one will say 's' and the next say 'how' or something like that.  But it depends on my data.